# Do laundered pointers destroy optimisation opportunities?

Tags: c++, optimization, language-lawyer, machine-code, stdlaunder

[`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) intentionally obfuscates the origin of a pointer for the abstract machine / the compiler so that source and result may have different lifetimes and types. When used for e.g. (static) vector situations where you have a semi-large storage holding a number of objects, laundering a "dry" pointer to a slice produces a clean but "wet" pointer (wet as in laundered) of the appropriate type:

```
// appropriately sized and aligned data member
std::byte* const dry = data + some_index;
T* const wet = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(dry));
```

The idea is that the compiler cannot "see" past `std::launder`. Even if no implementation lives in a separate compilation unit. The question is if this may still cost legitimate optimisation opportunities.

For example:

```
T object;
// ...
T* ptr = &object;
ptr->member = 42;
return ptr->member;
```

Presumably, the address of `object` and `member` does not need to be retrieved separately when reading its contents because it likely still sits in some register. But if access to `ptr` was always laundered, for example if it was retrieved from some `operator[](size_type)` that has to launder the storage pointer, this might no longer be true:

```
storage[i].member = 42;
return storage[i].member;
// storage[]() launders
```

- Is my understanding of optimisation fences correct?
- Does this mean re-loading of (sub-) objects on the assembly level has to occur *because of launder*?

  - If not, why not?
- Is there a way around this other than keeping a reference to `storage[i]`?
- Or should I rather think of `std::launder` as a function that does nothing but magically makes UB-code non-UB?

---

Implications: If this is correct, it would mean that vector-like structures (i.e. what you use when you need the most performance) would take a performance hit between C++14 and C++17 because of the introduction of `std::launder`. `std::vector<T>` would fall behind a simple `T*`.

Comment: `if this may cost legitimate optimisation opportunities` - one [should assume so](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171117-00/?p=97416).

Comment: I don't think that's what `std::launder` does. It doesn't have any implications for the "as-if" rule in the way that `volatile` does. Adding it changes a program execution with undefined behavior to an entirely valid program execution.

Comment: @gserg you linked to a post "The wrong way of benchmarking the most efficient integer comparison function" but I didn't find keyword `launder`. Could you explain a bit about it? Is it related to `const` propagation?

Comment: @LouisGo No, it's related to the fact that when the compiler can consider the code as a whole, it can optimize it better than when it has to optimize each function separately.

Comment: @GSerg This is not about separate compilation units. Assume the compiler can see all code, as if it all was implemented in header files.

Comment: Side note: I once tried to construct/find an example where `std::launder` changes something about the assembly. The only one I was able to find is the one from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder#Example), which is fairly obscure. So in my mental model, since it doesn't seem to do anything most of the time, it won't affect optimization most of the time.